# Transform Matrix to Binary values

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

Let's say i have this current matrix :

```
mat=[
    {'Blue'} {'Heavy'} {'Rounded'};
    {'White'} {'Light'} {'Square'};
    {'Green'} {'Light'} {'Rounded'};
    {'Blue'} {'Very Heavy'} {'Square'};
    {'White'} {'Light'} {'Rounded'};
    {'Green'} {'Very Heavy'} {'Square'};
    {'Blue'} {'Light'} {'Rounded'};
    {'White'} {'Very Heavy'} {'Square'};
    {'Green'} {'Very Heavy'} {'Rounded'};
    {'Blue'} {'Heavy'} {'Square'}];
```

First of i need to create an output of the matrix like this:

```
     Color       Weight         Form 
       _______    ____________    _______

V1     'Blue'     'Heavy'         'Rounded' 
V2     'White'    'Light'         'Square'
V3     'Green'     'Light'         'Rounded' 
V4     'Blue'     'Very Heavy'    'Square'
V5     'White'    'Light'         'Rounded' 
V6     'Green'     'Very Heavy'    'Square'
V7     'Blue'     'Light'         'Rounded' 
V8     'White'    'Very Heavy'    'Square'
V9     'Green'     'Very Heavy'    'Rounded' 
V10    'Blue'     'Heavy'         'Square'
```

What i would like to do is transform the elements in this matrix to Binary Values

I.e something similar to this :

codageVar =

```
 0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1
 1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
 1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
 0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1
 1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

Such as Blue is {010},White{100} and Green{001} As you can see there is no sense of order in this context
We can't say Blue>White or Blue

However for the Column Weight => Heavy{010},Light{100},Very Heavy{001} there should be a sense of order where
Very Heavy > Heavy > Light ,which means Very heavy should be coded {111} which translate to 7 (111 Binary = 7 Decimal)

What i'm aiming to do and hope you can help me with is creat an automated program which can take any small matrix as an input
Then ask the user which of these columns have a sense of order in them then code those variables in binary such as they are sorted in the Matrix

So in exemple : 
You write the matrix in the script

The program asks you this : How many columns are ordinal?
You answer i.e 2 
Then the program asks you what are the position of these two columns in the matrix
Answer : i.e 2 & 3
Then asks you what are these values
Answer i.e  Very Heavy,Heavy & light
It then "codes" all the matrix in binary but if the matrix has in total of 3 columns then 1st columns gets coded randomly in binary
But the elements in 2 & 3 should have an order to them (It does not mean to rearrange the matrix from big to small but just the binary values)

I'm quite new to matlab but here is what i was able to come up with

```
clear all
clc
mat=[
    {'Bleu'} {'Lourd'} {'Rond'};
    {'Blanc'} {'Léger'} {'Carre'};
    {'Vert'} {'Léger'} {'Rond'};
    {'Bleu'} {'Très Lourd'} {'Carre'};
    {'Blanc'} {'Léger'} {'Rond'};
    {'Vert'} {'Très Lourd'} {'Carre'};
    {'Bleu'} {'Léger'} {'Rond'};
    {'Blanc'} {'Très Lourd'} {'Carre'};
    {'Vert'} {'Très Lourd'} {'Rond'};
    {'Bleu'} {'Lourd'} {'Carre'}];



NomCol = {'Couleur','Poids','Forme'};


for i=1:size(mat,1)
NomLignes{i}=['V' '' num2str(i)];
end

sTable = array2table(mat,'VariableNames',NomCol,'RowNames',NomLignes)


codage=[];
y=0;

for i=1:size(mat,2) 

    v=mat(:,i); 
    un=unique(v); 

    code=eye(size(un,1));

    codage2=[];

    for i=1:size(v,1)

        pos=strmatch(v(i,:),un);

        b=code(pos,:);

        codage2=[codage2;b];


    end
    codage=[codage,codage2];
end



codage
```

I can code all the variables in  binary without any problem

codage =

```
 0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
 1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
 0     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0
```

How ever i need the Heavy,Very Heavy & Light values to have an ordinal sense to them so i.e Very Heavy should be = 1 1 1 / Heavy = 1 1 0 / Light = 1 0 0 because logically Very Heavy(7 in decimal) > Heavy(6 in decimal)

Please let me know if there is any given refined function or method i could do this

Answer (score 0):

Converting the matrix is simple:

```
% convert cell-matrix to table with specific column names
T = cell2table(mat,'VariableNames',{'Color','Weight','Form'});
```

automatically generating the binary keys is a bit more difficult, but matlab helps your with the function `de2bi`

```
% assuming that this is your user-input
InptKey = {'Blue','Green','White'};
% create binary keys
num_bin = de2bi(1:length(InptKey));
```

Now, the tricky part is indeed the checking

```
% allocate remporary variable
tmp = cast(zeros(height(T),size(num_bin,2)),class(num_bin));
% or simply use
tmp = false(height(T),size(num_bin,2));

% loop through rows
for i = 1:length(Inptkey)
    key = InptKey{i};
    val = num_bin(i,:);

    lg = strcmpi(T.Color,key);
    % depending on the Matlab version your are working with the first
    % option also works, see 'implicit expansion'. Otherwise you need 
% to expand "val" manually
%     tmp(lg,:) = val;
    tmp(lg,:) = repmat(val,sum(lg),1);
end
% assign 'tmp' variable (you need to assign the whole vector at once not to
% cause a conversion conflict from cell to logical)
T.Color = tmp;
```

Note that you cannot replace the strings directly with the binary vector since they are of different type (*cell* vs *logical*) so you need to use a temporary vector